# Typoscript for Powermail Checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, typo3, typoscript, powermail

In TYPO3 I built a Powermail form for frontend editing of extended fe_users. One field holds a comma separated list of categories, and I use a Typoscript lib to fill a group of checkboxes with the entries of sys_category for this field, trying to check the ones found in fe_users field. But there is no pre-selection.

Is it the nested CONTENT? Is it the renderObj? Where is the error? Any ideas?

```
lib.powermail.options {
category = CONTENT
category {
    table = sys_category
    select.pidInList = 41
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = TEXT
        10.field = title
        20 = TEXT
        20.value = |
        30 = TEXT
        30.field = uid
        40 = TEXT
        40.value = |*
        40.if.isInList.field = uid
        40.if.value = CONTENT
        40.if.value {
            table = fe_users
            select {
                pidInList = 41
                where.dataWrap = uid = {TSFE:fe_user|user|uid}
            }
            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj.field = category
        }
        stdWrap.wrap = |[\n]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What you mean with `pre-selection`?

Answer (score 0):

On the first view I can't see a problem. Nevertheless, if I have to build such a complex TypoScript object, I try to look at the result. Can you also use

```
page.1 < lib.powermail.options
```

and paste the result?

Comment: The result is a string in the form "Option-Label|Option-Value[\n]Option-Label2|Option-Value2[\n]"..., so the checkboxes will show all the available categories in the correct form, but the subquery does not mark them with "|*" to be checked, if the option value is in the fe_user's database field for the category.